# resizeable html svg image

Tags: html, svg, resize, responsive-design

I'm having fun on a little experiment trying to reduce http requests and play with svg instead of css3 stuff... Unable to set this HTML SVG to scale dynamically. Ideally, I'd like to set it's width and height to 50% and let the browser do the rest as the window resizes.

Here's the code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <title>Daniel Hutchinson</title>
  <g>
    <path d="m133.936,182.53101h-8.41701v77.21298h8.05002c21.40799,0 39.70398,-11.70999 39.70398,-38.60599c0.00101,-24.70099 -16.28299,-38.60699 -39.33699,-38.60699z" clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
    <path fill="black" d="m218.448,0c-120.646,0 -218.448,97.802 -218.448,218.448s97.802,218.448 218.448,218.448s218.448,-97.802 218.448,-218.448s-97.80301,-218.448 -218.448,-218.448zm-77.925,290.117h-50.86501v-137.95801h50.86501c38.423,0 70.07701,30.19 70.07701,68.97897s-31.83701,68.97903 -70.07701,68.97903zm210.22499,0h-35.862v-56.53699h-51.78v56.53699h-35.862v-137.95801h35.862v53.24402h51.78v-53.24402h35.862v137.95801l0,0z" clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: can't you use CSS to scale it?

Comment: I will be.. Ideally i'd set it's width to 50% in css and it would handle the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers won't scale SVG images properly unless you give them a `viewBox`, I arrived at these figures by quickly [experimenting in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/FnsyQ/), you could probably work out the exact vales needed with a little effort:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-10 -10 600 600">
```

You can also try specifying `width` and `height` attributes, different browsers respond to them in different ways, especially when you then size them with CSS.  A while back I knocked up [a test page which tried all the combinations when embedding SVG as an image](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/svg-as-image.html), it's worth comparing the different results in (for example) Firefox and Chrome.  I would expect using the SVG in CSS would give similar results.